# Why won't 'plymouth-quit-wait' start and why does my Fedora 17 hang on boot?

Tags: boot, fedora, freeze, services

When I try to boot after having done several updates, the boot animation "loads" and then flashes with the Fedora logo, and then sits there still.

After checking into it more I found that two services were failing to start:

1. `tcsd.service`, I was able to to disable `tcsd.service`, in the hopes I could boot without it.
2. `plymouth-quit-wait.service`, I have been unable to do anything to the second service.

I am running Fedora Core 17 and the akmod nvidia drivers, on an ASUS G53SW. Everything is up to date as far as I know.

Why won't these services (especially plymouth) start? What can I do to troubleshoot this and fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a [known issue with fedora 17](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=817462) - apparently rather than disabling the service (which dosen't work cause of some setup wierdness) you need to mask it with `systemctl mask plymouth-start.service`